# Beam column joint reinforcement

Tags: structural-engineering

[image]
Why cant we provide the bars cross bent in the beam column  joint...as the cracks are all diagonal...so inorder to avoid cracks why cant we provide the bars crossed in the joint instead of providing mess of vertical and horizontal steel?

Answer (score 1):

We have created a very weak joint ready to break this way. like a perforated paper encouraging tear line.

The top and bottom of the column are connected via that X reinforcement which is susceptible to crack and rotation.

Rebar continuity into the joint ensures rigidity of the joint. in some joints we may even add additional straight vertical and horizontal bars parallel to continuous pars for extra strength of the joint.

Answer (score 0):

If the joint cracks as shown, you have had a big problem, as it indicates the concrete fails in compression with random failure patterns - the concrete is crumbling, for which the diagonally placed reinforcement solves nothing but hurting the concrete core - by its tendency to straighten and buckle that would create additional stress and splinting the concrete.

Same as the reason for ties improve the performance of a column - to provide necessary confining stress to protect the concrete core bonded by the reinforcement. At a beam-column joint, in addition to the surrounding beams and columns, the straight main reinforcement in both directions forms a loop that essentially provides additional confining stress to the core, to protect the core from excessive stresses due to the effects of combined forces and deformations.

[image]
Hope this helps.